# Pygame rectangles all bunching up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, rendering, pygame-surface

I am making a game where every day you chop wood. I decided to make the trees into a class, but when I did it, I got all the drawn rectangles that make up a tree all bunch up together in the same position. At least I think it did that, because only one tree would appear. The entire code is below:

```py
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
root = pygame.display.set_mode((603, 573))
pygame.display.set_caption("Homework")
window_is_open = True
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
width = 10
leaves_width = 30
height = 20
leaves_height = 10
x = 0
tree_trunk_x = 10
y = 0
tree_trunk_y = 10
vel = 5
brown = (150, 75, 0)
green = (58, 95, 11)
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, tree_x, tree_y, tree_property_name):
         global pos_x
         global pos_y
         global tree_property
         pos_x = tree_x
         pos_y = tree_y
         tree_property = tree_property_name
    def destroy(self):
        count = pygame.font.SysFont('Tahoma', 18, True, False)
        root.fill(white)
        countdown = count.render('3', True, (0, 0, 0))
        root.blit(countdown, (583, 553))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        count = pygame.font.SysFont('Tahoma', 18, True, False)
        root.fill(white)
        countdown = count.render('2', True, (0, 0, 0))
        root.blit(countdown, (583, 553))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        count = pygame.font.SysFont('Tahoma', 18, True, False)
        root.fill(white)
        countdown = count.render('1', True, (0, 0, 0))
        root.blit(countdown, (583, 553))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        tree_property = False
    def create_tree(self):
        if tree_property:
            trunk_x = pos_x + 10
            trunk_y = pos_y + 10
            pygame.draw.rect(root, brown, (trunk_x, trunk_y, width, height))
            pygame.draw.rect(root, green, (pos_x, pos_y, leaves_width, leaves_height))
    def redraw(self):
        self.create_tree()
tree_one_property = True
tree_two_property = True
tree_three_property = True
tree_four_property = True
tree_five_property = True
tree_six_property = True
tree_seven_property = True
tree_eight_property = True
tree_nine_property = True
tree_ten_property = True
tree_eleven_property = True
tree_twelve_property = True
tree_thirteen_property = True
tree_fourteen_property = True
tree_fifteen_property = True
tree_sixteen_property = True
tree_seventeen_property = True
tree_eighteen_property = True
tree_nineteen_property = True
tree_twenty_property = True
tree_twenty_one_property = True
tree_twenty_two_property = True
tree_twenty_three_property = True
tree_twenty_four_property = True
tree_twenty_five_property = True
tree_one = Tree(0, 0, tree_one_property)
tree_two = Tree(50, 0, tree_two_property)
tree_three = Tree(100, 0, tree_three_property)
tree_four = Tree(150, 0, tree_four_property)
tree_five = Tree(200, 0, tree_five_property)
tree_six = Tree(0, 50, tree_six_property)
tree_eight = Tree(100, 50, tree_eight_property)
tree_seven = Tree(50, 50, tree_seven_property)
tree_nine = Tree(150, 50, tree_nine_property)
tree_ten = Tree(200, 50, tree_ten_property)
tree_eleven = Tree(0, 100, tree_eleven_property)
tree_twelve = Tree(50, 100, tree_twelve_property)
tree_thirteen = Tree(100, 100, tree_thirteen_property)
tree_fourteen = Tree(150, 100, tree_fourteen_property)
tree_fifteen = Tree(200, 100, tree_fifteen_property)
tree_sixteen = Tree(0, 150, tree_sixteen_property)
tree_seventeen = Tree(50, 150, tree_seventeen_property)
tree_eighteen = Tree(100, 150, tree_eighteen_property)
tree_nineteen = Tree(150, 150, tree_nineteen_property)
tree_twenty = Tree(200, 150, tree_twenty_property)
tree_twenty_one = Tree(0, 200, tree_twenty_one_property)
tree_twenty_two = Tree(50, 200, tree_twenty_two_property)
tree_twenty_three = Tree(100, 200, tree_twenty_three_property)
tree_twenty_four = Tree(150, 200, tree_twenty_four_property)
tree_twenty_five = Tree(200, 200, tree_twenty_five_property)
root.fill(white)
while window_is_open:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            window_is_open = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_q]:
        tree_one.destroy()
    root.fill(white)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Tahoma', 18, True, False)
    score = font.render('Score:', True, (0, 0, 0))
    root.blit(score, (410, 0))
    rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(root, (0, 0, 0), (x, y, width, 10)) 
    tree_one.redraw()
    tree_two.redraw()
    tree_three.redraw()
    tree_four.redraw()
    tree_five.redraw()
    tree_six.redraw()
    tree_seven.redraw()
    tree_eight.redraw()
    tree_nine.redraw()
    tree_ten.redraw()
    tree_eleven.redraw()
    tree_twelve.redraw()
    tree_thirteen.redraw()
    tree_fourteen.redraw()
    tree_fifteen.redraw()
    tree_sixteen.redraw()
    tree_seventeen.redraw()
    tree_eighteen.redraw()
    tree_nineteen.redraw()
    tree_twenty.redraw()
    tree_twenty_one.redraw()
    tree_twenty_two.redraw()
    tree_twenty_three.redraw()
    tree_twenty_four.redraw()
    tree_twenty_five.redraw()
    pygame.display.update()    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Are all this code nessecary to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a class, then you have to use [instance attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) (using `self.`), rather than global variables. e.g:

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, tree_x, tree_y, tree_property_name):
         self.pos_x = tree_x
         self.pos_y = tree_y
         self.tree_property = tree_property_name

    # [...]

    def create_tree(self):
        if self.tree_property:
            trunk_x = self.pos_x + 10
            trunk_y = self.pos_y + 10
            pygame.draw.rect(root, brown, (trunk_x, trunk_y, width, height))
            pygame.draw.rect(root, green, (self.pos_x, self.pos_y, leaves_width, leaves_height))
```

Note, a global variable exists once, but an instance attribute exists for each object (instance) of the class. Thus each `Tree` object has its own position.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a way to find possible errors. Whenever you have multiple Objects of the same type, use a list or a dictionary. This will avoid multiple variables like `tree_1`, `tree_2` etc.

```
tree_list = []
for _ in range(5):
    i = Tree()
    tree_list.append(i)
```

`tree_1` is then `tree_list[0]` etc.